# Resolve Merge Module File removal issue of 2 MSI application

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, merge-module

Assume **1 Merge Module(MSM) file which has 100 components** , is added as a feature in 2 MSI applications.
**1 MSI installs the MSM component** on installation as one of its feature. In 2nd MSI , there is condition set so that the install level of feature having the MSM is set to "0" , which means the **MSM component is not installed again through 2nd MSI**. Now Both MSI are installed in the system .

Issue is when I uninstall 1st MSI , all the MSM components are removed . How to keep the Merge module components so that its usable by remaining client i.e., 2nd MSI ?
Even though 2nd MSI , didnt install these component due to condition , **those components should not be removed by the 1st MSI.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Feature Condition so both Features reference track the required Components properly.

The Windows Installer will then remove the Components only when both Features are uninstalled